# 2 Datepickers as spinners in android

Tags: android, datepicker, spinner

i got some issues with my 2 datepickers as spinners in android. The first one is the check-in date and the second is check-out date. I want my checkout date automatically jump to the next day when i select the checkin one and vice versa when i select the checkout date, the checkin date automatically jumps to the previous day. I tried a lot but found no way to this setup. I always ended up an infinite loop cause this triggered that and that triggered back this and my app crashed. Do you guys have any solution to this? Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution**

*activity_main.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <DatePicker
            android:id="@+id/checkInDatePicker"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:calendarViewShown="false"
            android:datePickerMode="spinner" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/checkInDayOfWeek"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <DatePicker
            android:id="@+id/checkOutDatePicker"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
            android:calendarViewShown="false"
            android:datePickerMode="spinner" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/checkOutDayOfWeek"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

*MainActivity.java*

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements DatePicker.OnDateChangedListener {

    private DatePicker checkInDatePicker;
    private DatePicker checkOutDatePicker;
    private TextView checkInDayOfWeekTextView;
    private TextView checkOutDayOfWeekTextView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        checkInDatePicker = findViewById(R.id.checkInDatePicker);
        checkOutDatePicker = findViewById(R.id.checkOutDatePicker);
        checkInDayOfWeekTextView = findViewById(R.id.checkInDayOfWeek);
        checkOutDayOfWeekTextView = findViewById(R.id.checkOutDayOfWeek);

        Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
        int year = now.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = now.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int dayOfMonth = now.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        checkInDatePicker.init(year, month, dayOfMonth, this);
        checkInDayOfWeekTextView.setText(getDayOfWeek(now));
        checkOutDatePicker.init(year, month, dayOfMonth, this);
        checkOutDayOfWeekTextView.setText(getDayOfWeek(now));
    }

    @Override
    public void onDateChanged(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
        if (view.getId() == checkInDatePicker.getId()) {
            // Update check in day of week.
            Calendar checkInDay = Calendar.getInstance();
            checkInDay.set(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);
            String checkInDayOfWeek = getDayOfWeek(checkInDay);
            checkInDayOfWeekTextView.setText(checkInDayOfWeek);

            // Update check out DatePicker
            checkOutDatePicker.init(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth, null);
            Calendar nextDay = getNextDay(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);
            checkOutDatePicker.init(nextDay.get(Calendar.YEAR),
                    nextDay.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                    nextDay.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH),
                    this);

            // Update check out day of week.
            String checkOutDayOfWeek = getDayOfWeek(nextDay);
            checkOutDayOfWeekTextView.setText(checkOutDayOfWeek);
        } else {
            // Update check out day of week.
            Calendar checkOutDay = Calendar.getInstance();
            checkOutDay.set(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);
            String checkOutDayOfWeek = getDayOfWeek(checkOutDay);
            checkOutDayOfWeekTextView.setText(checkOutDayOfWeek);

            // Update check in DatePicker
            checkInDatePicker.init(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth, null);
            Calendar prevDay = getPreviousDay(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);
            checkInDatePicker.init(
                    prevDay.get(Calendar.YEAR),
                    prevDay.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                    prevDay.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH),
                    this);

            // Update check in day of week.
            String checkInDayOfWeek = getDayOfWeek(prevDay);
            checkInDayOfWeekTextView.setText(checkInDayOfWeek);
        }
    }

    private Calendar getNextDay(int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.set(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);
        calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
        return calendar;
    }

    private Calendar getPreviousDay(int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.set(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);
        calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -1);
        return calendar;
    }

    private String getDayOfWeek(Calendar calendar) {
        String dayOfWeek = "";

        switch (calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)) {
            case Calendar.SUNDAY:
                dayOfWeek = "Sunday";
                break;
            case Calendar.MONDAY:
                dayOfWeek = "Monday";
                break;
            case Calendar.TUESDAY:
                dayOfWeek = "Tuesday";
                break;
            case Calendar.WEDNESDAY:
                dayOfWeek = "Wednesday";
                break;
            case Calendar.THURSDAY:
                dayOfWeek = "Thursday";
                break;
            case Calendar.FRIDAY:
                dayOfWeek = "Friday";
                break;
            case Calendar.SATURDAY:
                dayOfWeek = "Saturday";
                break;
        }

        return dayOfWeek;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. It works just fine but your method like setOnDateChangedListener targets API 26 and above. Do you have any possible way working with lower API and what should I do if I want to add day of week beside my picker. Just a text which displays day of the week, no need selectable like a picker.

Comment: @sai Glad to hear that, if this answer solved your problem, please accept it as the answer, it will help me improve my answer in the future. Happy coding :)